# navbar layout with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have recently been exploring bootstrap and I am struggling with my nav bar. The code below shows how I would like it to look, the problem arises when I resize the browser window like a mobile phone. When I click on the hotdog button it only shows me the option to add username and password but I would also like to have access to the links. In order for me to get the layout I am looking for I have used two nav bars. I think that this is my issue. How can I achieve the same layout but with only one nav bar? I would like to to see all links and password boxes when the window is small, I am also trying to get rid of the black line that shows that there is two nav bars.

```
 <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp; &nbsp; Website Name</a>
            </div>
            <center>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MatchedManager</a>-->
            </div>
            <center>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
                <ul class="nav navbar-left navbar-nav">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Another action</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Forgot Login</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or a codepen demo. Otherwise it's hard to see what you are asking

Comment: Please find at: http://codepen.io/karl001/full/xZBjKj .If you resize the window you should see what I mean when the screen goes to the size of a mobile phone screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do this with one `navbar`. You simply create another div for your links and position them accordingly. Nothing else to it.

See working example Snippet at FullPage.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .lower-nav {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Website Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
      </form>
      <div class="lower-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Forgot Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. How can I get the full code?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? The modal allows you to add more options such as "register" or "forgot password" without necessarily needing them on the `nav` itself. Additionally, on mobile devices, it wouldn't show two navbars and instead would collapse normally.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sign In</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[codepen.io/zanderl/pen/mVoLdY](http://codepen.io/zanderl/pen/mVoLdY)